# Trying to write to External/SD storage in Android

Tags: android, file, permissions, storage

I'm trying to write a file to the SD card on android but i cannot get it to work properly. I'm using an Emulator with Android 6.0, where the app manifest has

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And as far as i understand it, for this to work the user must grant the permission at run time too. I have this code with some explanation inline as comments:

```
public class AboutPref extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {   

    private static final int WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.about_preferences);

        Preference export_settings = findPreference("export_settings");
        export_settings.setOnPreferenceClickListener(exportSettings());
        
    }
    
    // The export_settings Preference acts like a button, where this is called when it is clicked/tapped
    // it basically checks if the permission is already granted, and if so, doesn't bother asking the user for it again
    private Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener exportSettings()
    {
        return new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                //SettingsHelper.ExportSettings(getContext(), getActivity());

                int checkVal = getContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if(checkVal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                    askForStoragePermission();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.permission_explained)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, dialogClickListener)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    doExportSettings();
                }

                return false;
            }
        };
    }
    
    // This is called if the user had not given permission earlier as shown above
    public void askForStoragePermission()
    {
        List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        String[] permissions = permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]);
        requestPermissions(permissions, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    
    // When the user had not given permission earlier this is called after the permission request alert is closed
    // which once again checks if permission is granted or not
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case WRITE_REQUEST_CODE:               
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    doExportSettings();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed! Need permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    }
    
    // and this is the actualy method that is run when permission is/was granted
    private void doExportSettings()
    {
        // This one is simple for now, but will be used to write application settings to a file
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String exportFileName = "ApplicaitonName/app_settings.pwt";

        File file = new File(sdcard, exportFileName);
        try {
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            out.write(prefs.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("export error => " + e.getMessage()); // <-- BUT this happens
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        // .. not used but required
    }   
}
```

But as stated i get the following error: `export error => /storage/emulated/0/ApplicaitonName/app_settings.pwt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`

I must be missing something obvious no?

Comment: You need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to write. You also need to create the directory first, before attempting to write there. And your code will not work on Android 11+ devices, as you can no longer create arbitrary directories in arbitrary locations on external storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Doh I ofcourse i need to use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for this.. Will try it out thanks! On Android 11+ devices, how can i accomplish this task then?

Comment: The best solution on Android 5.1+ is to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and let the *user* choose where on the *user's* device (or the *user's* cloud storage) that your app should put the *user's* content. If you only need a single piece of content, then `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` would be simpler and works back to Android 5.0.

Comment: Thanks i will look into that ! My app is compatible all the way back to Android 4.1.. What are my options there?

Comment: For 4.1 through 5.0, you would need to use something like our current approach.